# Error Microsoft.VJSharp.VJSharpCodeProvide

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I installed visual studio 2008 in our server and tried to run our proejct on the server but i got this error
The CodeDom provider type "Microsoft.VJSharp.VJSharpCodeProvider, VJSharpCodeProvider, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" could not be located.
Do you have any  idea what is my problem?

Comment: I have to say we use windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The J# support assemblies are not included in .NET, it is a [separate download](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=4712).

Comment: +1 I got the Same Problem.Your answer resolved it. Below links also helped to me. [Check this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1562439.aspx/1) and [Refer this Link also Click Here..](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/4c6fce15-c7d1-43e9-a7d5-5eeb6da2a70b)

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2010, in addition to installing [Microsoft Visual J# Version 2.0 Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=4712), adding the following to Web.config within the main `<configuration>` tag seemed to also be required:

```
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="vj#;vjs;vjsharp" extension=".jsl;.java" type="Microsoft.VJSharp.VJSharpCodeProvider, VJSharpCodeProvider, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"></compiler>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be your project may include some Java related files and due to it this error can come,

Ref :- http://blogs.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/posts/07-12-02/the-codedom-provider-type-microsoft-vjsharp-vjsharpcodeprovider-could-not-be-located.aspx

can also manually find "JSON" or java files and can delete it if not need.