# The CodeDom provider type "Microsoft.VJSharp.VJSharpCodeProvider, VJSharpCodeProvider could not be located

Tags: c#, asp.net

Created a website which was working properly. Recently PC was formatted and after migration of website it gives error while compilation

```
"The CodeDom provider type "Microsoft.VJSharp.VJSharpCodeProvider, VJSharpCodeProvider, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a could not be located"
```

Why suddenly website is asking for the above reference?

Comment: check this site https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560321/error-microsoft-vjsharp-vjsharpcodeprovide

Comment: Tried.but problem still exist.